# try-except не перехватывает исключения

Tags: python

```
    try:
        print('=====ДО=====')
        os.remove(file)
        print('=====ПОСЛЕ=====')
    except:
        print('Этот принт выполняется')
        exit(f'Не удаляется {file}')
```

Впервые с таким сталкиваюсь. Может быть кто знает объяснение. Блок except не срабатывает.

```
def rrr():
    try:
        1/0
    except:
        exit(10000)

try:
    rrr()
except:
    print(54545)
```

выполнение rrr() - дает вывод 10000
выполнение всего кода давет вывод 54545, хотя ожидал того же 10000

Выполнение в консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выполнение во вкладке RUN. Результат неожиданно разный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кстати, file оказался занят другим приложением. Если его освободить, полностью выполняется блок try. Почему блок exit не выполняется?

Comment: а если не укажу, то не перехватит?

Comment: перепроверил, блок except выполняется. Не выполняется exit

Comment: А что за функция `exit`? Может попытка её выполнения тоже исключение бросает?

Comment: я так и подумал. Но file - это строка, проверил принтом :)

Comment: добавил изменение

Comment: Ещё раз спрашиваю - что за `exit`? И в какой среде выполняете вы код, не в интерактивном ли питоне?

Comment: именно sys.exit()

Comment: Отличный вопрос про среду. Если в консоли - то ответ правильный 10000. Если в среде пайчарм - ответ 54545

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну на самом деле вы просто не понимаете, как в питоне происходит выход из программы по `sys.exit`. При этом просто бросается исключение `SystemExit`. Так устроен питон. И это исключение ловится у вас во внешнем блоке `try/except`. Именно поэтому важно прописывать конкретные исключения, которые вы хотите ловить в блоке `except`, а не ловить все исключения подряд.

Если ловить хотя бы `Exception`, то `SystemExit` уже не поймается:

```
try:
    rrr()
except Exception:
    print(54545)
```

Вывод:

```
SystemExit: 10000
```

Это потому, что исключение `SystemExit` унаследовано от `BaseException`, а не от `Exception`.

Почему получается разный результат в консоли и в `PyCharm` не подкажу, но, видимо, это тоже как-то завязано на обработку исключения `SystemExit` самой средой выполнения (интерактивным питоном в каком-то из случаев, видимо).

Comment: Если сделать так: def rrr():
    try:
        1/0
    except SystemExit:
        sys.exit(10000). То ответ в среде PM будет тот же

Comment: @ЮрийСтрашко Вы что-то странное делаете этим кодом. `1/0` бросает исключение `ZeroDivisionError`, конечно, оно не поймается как `SystemExit` в блоке `except` и `sys.exit(10000)` просто не выполнится.

Comment: да, но тогда верно было отлавливать все исключения и оно отловилось. Просто exit не выполнилась в среде PM

Comment: @ЮрийСтрашко Ну, вам в любом случае нужно разобраться как работают исключения и какие они бывают. Будет гораздо меньше вопросов потом.